# Windows won't allow update until CA Internet Security Suite is uninstalled

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I have this problem with a Windows 10 computer I'm trying to update. When I try to update the computer, I get a prompt saying it fails because Windows couldn't uninstall some apps. The app specifically being talked is called "CA Internet Security Suite" which after some Googling is found to be a long defunct suite of security tools from an obsolete company.  I went to this (https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5382-computer-associates-uninstaller.html) link, but the download link redirects to a broken site. 
Here is what I've done:
1. Gone to add/remove programs. The program "CA Internet Security Suite" doesn't exist.
2. Checked all program files. Couldn't find even a whiff of it.
3. Gone to the Windows Registry. Couldn't find any keys registered to it. 
4. Searched on the Google. Got nowhere.
I don't know what to do from here. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

CA security suite used to be installed as Comcast’s internet security suite.

It is now called Total Defense.

Microsoft offers the following site with a list of anti-malware cleanup tools: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_other-protect_start-windows_other/list-of-anti-malware-product-removal-tools/2bcb53f7-7ab4-4ef9-ab3a-6aebfa322f75

They suggest using the [OESIS Endpoint Assessment Tool](https://www.opswat.com/products/oesis-framework/free-tools/endpoint-assessment-tool) which is capable of removing multiple anti-malware products.

Seems like the link on the MS site is broken. It’s possible the endpoint assessment tool is being discontinued. However it appears to be available for download from a few software providers like CNET and Softpedia. http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Uninstallers/AppRemover.shtml

Comment: Your product link goes to a 404 error page.